# matplotlib not share axis x with many sub plots

Tags: matplotlib

I want to draw a chart with several sub-charts. The axes X have different lengths. The shape will be like:
    subchart 1: ---------
    subchart 2: --------------
    subchart 3: ------------------

But i don't know how.

Comment: It's not very clear from your question what you are expecting. My guess is a [vertical bar chart](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/barh_demo.html)? Try to just make the simplest thing you can using an example, then extend it. When you get stuck you'll then have a better idea of what the question is.

Comment: @Greg Hi Greg, it is like vertical bar, but the bar is replaced by other plots. It is like several sub plots with different length of x axis (not the scale, but the actual length of axis.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [gridspec](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html) to make subplots of different sizes.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (0,0), colspan=1)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (1,0), colspan=2)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (2,0), colspan=3)

plt.show()
```

[image: gridspec example]